# Regular expression substitution in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string

`line = "haha (as jfeoiwf) avsrv arv (as qwefo) afneoifew"`

From this I want to remove all instances of `"(as...)"` using some regular expression. I want the output to look like

`line = "haha avsrv arv afneoifew"`

I tried:

```
line = re.sub(r'\(+as .*\)','',line)
```

But this yields:

`line = "haha  afneoifew"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get [non-greedy behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy), you have to use `*?` instead of `*`, ie `re.sub(r'\(+as .*?\) ','',line)`. To get the desired string, you also have to add a space, ie `re.sub(r'\(+as .*?\) ','',line)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your regexp matches this whole group : `(as jfeoiwf) avsrv arv (as qwefo)`, hence your result.

You can use :

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "haha (as jfeoiwf) avsrv arv (as qwefo) afneoifew"
>>> line = re.sub(r'\(+as [a-zA-Z]*\)','',line)
>>> line
'haha  avsrv arv  afneoifew'
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. You need to use lazy quantifier '?' after .*. In default it will try to capture biggest group it possibly can. With lazy quantifier it'll actually try to match smallest possible groups.

```
line = re.sub(r'\(+as .*?\) ','',line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
re.sub(u".\(as \w+\).", ' ',line)
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
re.sub(r'\(as[^\)]*\)', '', line)
```